# Output datas from a multidimensional array whiteout looping in it with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've this type of array structure:

```
$fruits = array(
    array(
        'name'      => 'Banana',
        'continent' => 'Africa', 
        'counts'    => array(
            'standard'  => 15,
            'advanced'  => 20
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name'      => 'Apple',
        'continent' => 'Europa', 
        'counts'    => array(
            'standard'  => 25,
            'advanced'  => 25
        )
    )
);
```

How without looping in it (foreach), I can output from this array one data ?

For example, I would like to write this :
In `Europa`, I can find `25` `standard` `Apple`.

So I tried this without any result:

```
<?
    echo 'In ';
    echo $fruits['name']['Banana']=>'continent';
    echo ', I can find ';
    ...
    echo '.'.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a try like this by wrapping your nested array variables in curly braces `{}`
See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
<?php
$fruits = array(
    array(
        'name'      => 'Banana',
        'continent' => 'Africa', 
        'counts'    => array(
            'standard'  => 15,
            'advanced'  => 20
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name'      => 'Apple',
        'continent' => 'Europa', 
        'counts'    => array(
            'standard'  => 25,
            'advanced'  => 25
        )
    )
);
//In Europa, I can find 25 standard Apple.
$key = array_keys($fruits[1]['counts'])[0];
echo "In {$fruits[1]['continent']}, I can find {$fruits[1]['counts']['standard']} {$key} {$fruits[1]['name']}";
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/KoQiO

Answer (score 0):

If you know the result data index then you can get output without a loop for a single record.

But If you want whole records to print, then for-each should be a must. Below code is for your current record.

```
echo 'In ' . $fruits[1]["continent"] . ', I can find ' . $fruits[1]["counts"]["standard"] . ' standard ' . $fruits[1]["name"] . '.';
```